# Unity InjectionConstructor Passing Object array

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am trying to register dependency using unity and pass values to constructor,using the code below

```
container.RegisterType<IProviderContext, MockOrderServiceProviderContext>(new InjectionConstructor(new Pharmacy {SiteId = 2,DistrictCode = "2"}));
```

but I am getting

> "The type OrderService.Business.MockOrderServiceProviderContext does
>   not have a constructor that takes the parameters (Pharmacy)."

Constructor.

```
public MockOrderServiceProviderContext(params object[] objects)
     {
         _object = objects;
     }
```

How do you pass constructor values for object array ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The params keyword is syntactic sugar for passing an array of arguments.

The following method:

```
public void MyMethod(params object[] args)
{
}
```

Can be invoked in both of the following ways with the same results:

```
MyMethod(new object(), new object());
MyMethod(new []{ new object(), new object());
```

When Unity looks for constructors, it sees a constructor with one parameter of type `object[]`. So the value provided by Unity must be an array.

The `InjectionConstructor` also utilises the params keyword, where each parameter is a value to forward to your own constructor. If you instantiate the `InjectionConstructor` with an array, it will try and use each element of the array and forward them to your class constructor.

To stop this, we require two levels of wrapping, one for unity to provide an array to your class, and one so that the `InjectionConstructor` uses the first array as the first and only parameter.

So you should use the following:

```
container.RegisterType<IProviderContext, MockOrderServiceProviderContext>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new []
    {
       new []
       {
           new Pharmacy { SiteId = 2, DistrictCode = "2" }
       }
    }));
```

If you want additional items to be passed, merely add them to the inner array:

```
container.RegisterType<IProviderContext, MockOrderServiceProviderContext>(
    new InjectionConstructor(new []
    {
       new []
       {
           new Pharmacy { SiteId = 2, DistrictCode = "2" },
           new Hospital { SiteId = 5, DistrictCode="2" }
       }
    }));
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation about params and injectionconstructor

Comment: @JoR No problem, I hope it made sense.

Comment: Very helpful explanation, even 3 years later!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got it working.

You have to add objects to an array and then add them to a container array so that it matches with the constructor parameter signature

```
var objAr = new object[2];
objAr[0] = new Pharmacy { SiteId = 3, DistrictCode = "2" };
objAr[1] = new Facility { SiteID = 1, FacilityCode="Facility" };

//Add the object array to another container array so that Unity Injection constructor can match the constructor.
var containerArray = new object[1];
containerArray[0] = objAr;

container.RegisterType<IProviderContext, MockOrderServiceProviderContext>(new InjectionConstructor(containerArray));
```

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't you trying to give a paramater with your `MockOrderServiceProviderContext` which isn't an array?

You give `new InjectionConstructor(..)` as a parameter instead, or `object` if you like to say so, instead of `object[]`.

Comment: Actually no. The idea of having object array is so that we can pass multiple objects. Like `new InjectionConstructor(new Pharmacy {SiteId = 2,DistrictCode = "2"},new Hospital {ID =1,name="SSS"}` Thanks

Comment: @joetjah In the registration with Unity, the parameters to `InjectionConstructor` are used to determine the parameters when injecting the values. The `InjectionConstructor` is not actually used as a parameter value.